# Weird python error - I/O error No such file of directory

Tags: python

I am trying to open python prompt and run the below code:

```
>>> a=open("Andrew_Smith_(author/education_professional)_0",'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'Andrew_Smith_(author/education_professional)_0'
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error. I know the file contains special characters, but I am asking it to create a new file.

**Edit:**

I cannot use -, as some names might contain '-'. I also don't want to use space. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Do you really have a directory named "Andrew_Smith_(author"?

Comment: use another char..it's so difficult to find one?

Comment: If you have no directory named "Andrew_Smith_(author" then you have an IO Error.  The directory doesn't exist.

Comment: How about using '_' as an alternative or perhaps a combination of possibly nested '[' and ']' pairs if you want to represent some sort of categorical (non-filesystem) hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said the issue is the `/`, it is looking for a directory named `Andrew_Smith_(author` to create the new file `education_professional)_0` in.

```
bash-3.2# mkdir "Andrew_Smith_(author"
bash-3.2# python
>>> a=open("Andrew_Smith_(author/education_professional)_0", 'w')
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a `/` character in your filename. Neither *NIX nor Windows typically allow this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two problems here.  First is because of the '/' character.  It can't distinguish between / in a file name (which isn't valid) and / as a path seperator.  And second, I don't believe '(' or ')' are valid in path names either.

Comment: Actually, `(` and `)` are perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using reserved characters -- remove the `/` (or replace it with, for example, `-`) and everything should just work.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use -, as some names might contain '-'. Any other alternative?

Comment: I can use space, but is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Algorist -- my best bet would be `-` or `_`.  ` and ` might also work, or `__slash__` if you want to be able to re-translate the file name into the string.  Just thoughts.